# Пожалуйста, помогите решить задачу

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, функции, циклы

Надо написать функцию, которая будет заменять все повторяющиеся символы в строке на ")", а неповторяющиеся на "(". Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

Сам я написал вот это, но оно не работает

```js
function duplicateEncode(word){
    let result = "";
    for(i = 0; i <= word.length; i++ ) {
      let isIt = word.indexOf(word[i], 0);
      if(isIt == -1) {
        result += ')';
      }else{
        result += '(';
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: нужно просто добавить функцию, которая возвращает отображение букв на количество их повторений. А дальше используете свою функцию с небольшими изменениями. PS: хотя можно и решение John использовать. Правда, у John оценочная сложность -- `O(n^2)`, хотя можно сделать за `O(n)` с небольшой потерей в читаемости кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
 function duplicateEncode(word){
     let result = "";
     for(i = 0; i < word.length; i++ ) {
         if(word.indexOf(word[i]) != word.lastIndexOf(word[i]) ) {
            result += ')';
         }else{
            result += '(';
         }
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Comment: С багом работает. В конце добавляет лишнюю скобку.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after condition

Comment: @AlexDevTime не заметил, автор  в цикле условие поставил в цикле  `<=` - поправил

Answer (score 2):

```js
function duplicateEncode(word){
    return [...word].map((c, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(c) == arr.lastIndexOf(c) ? ')' : '(').join('');
}

console.log(duplicateEncode('abcabdef'))
```

Answer (score 1):

### просто ещё один способ

```js
const isRaw = (q) => q instanceof Object && 'raw' in q;
const raw2str = (str) => isRaw(str) ? String.raw(str) : str;
// --
function replace(_str, props = new replace.Props) {
    const r = (str, i, arr) => (delete arr[i], props.ignoreList && props.ignoreList.has(str) ? str : props.setList.has(str) ? props.A : !!~arr.indexOf(str) ? (props.setList.add(str), props.A) : props.B || str);
    return Array
        .from(raw2str(_str))
        .map(r)
        .join(props.sep);
}
(function (replace) {
    class Props {
        constructor(props) {
            this.A = '-';
            this.ignoreList = new Set(['\n', ' ']);
            this.sep = '';
            this.setList = new Set();
            Object.assign(this, props);
        }
    }
    replace.Props = Props;
})(replace || (replace = {}));
// --
hyperHTML.bind(document.body) `
<pre class="q">
    <div class="q b">
        Задание просто.
        Написать функцию, которая будет заменять символы в строке
        - повторяющиеся на ")",
        - неповторяющиеся на "("
    </div>
    <div class="q r">${replace `
        Задание просто.
        Написать функцию, которая будет заменять символы в строке
        - повторяющиеся на ")",
        - неповторяющиеся на "("
        `}
    </div>
</pre>
`;
```

```css
q {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
div.q {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.q.b  { visibility: hidden; }
.q.r  { visibility: visible;  }
pre.q:hover .b  { visibility: visible;  }
pre.q:hover .r  { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/hyperhtml@latest/min.js"></script>
```

---

а там: [немного типов и коментов](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?alwaysStrict=false&allowUnusedLabels=true&esModuleInterop=false&skipLibCheck=true&allowJs=true&declaration=false&module=0#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8AWBPADiGAJAKgLIAyAXPAC5YgD2AZvAJYC2mNMFAFAOQbYyoKzCNwCUAbgBQAemnwAtPMlgaAOwDOFJuoBKUAO7wAvPE4BHclFXpR5M9vj4QraBRABlCjEaqA5uoBBGBgodGMAPnh7H00rMFoGAHkAIwArcC0AMkz4bhD9biZVKKkVDS18gCZNGGNTGvInFyg3T28-QODQ%20AAfeBqfX1t%20r0GI7T19ThrReAB%20eDbBgDp86a9Z8hqpWQUlOgBXVTAKRjV4OExoeM4AfQbHZyuWj1GOoJCwvoG-ABp4TAwGiYdTkS7XEDLAAKQJBdVUIEM4Kg8WhsPUwx%20vngAG9JPACfAypoLnV1jAtm9fP9GORVAdmMkcP9YBSRu1fABtAC6syMkU4oAgIDc8FZnMY3P%20gOB6mWjF8qnYIGIjBJ2QB6PliuVqs0y1QUHU5NmCxq8HIMpBy3UIr1FANRpN801suWAQt8AAhF6AH6s%20WqUAAD0SdGdC04Vrltoo9uWUGAwBN0q1AU2rutACFet8NvjCXAKAcYMUPqEC4TCcs6EDmJwqjU7jNRJWq-BlswoJgG6329XUjQfFGtbbMBJJABfSSqKDMEDqTAohDI%20K4tsgYNsDhE6DqdTwGGy9f9gnSABU5-ggEEQQAcIIAeEEATCCAPhBANwg8EA7CCABhB74BWEEAvCCANIgCjwIA-CDPo%20gBCIM%20gACIIA8iCAHIggCSILev7XnB8DntIbZVpgBzJBAjBgPAASUhydTcPI3BSKe8AXled5Pm%20n4-gBwHyPAgDCIP%20t6AFwgX6voAMiBAb%20mHYbReEEUR8BZuQRygHQPggMAvTsoMNGnvRBJYThhKSYRxEKkqcD2nSBwQBAqnuCKAA8WKRCYCKGNZXCctwAA6qjcP8hTcLyGn9lpMFfh%20gAsIL%20r63pBEWCdp4mnvp0ljmRYwmNw1G6Wel6LLZ9kgeBUGwYhKFoRhYmZQC%20EGf0dpqhQ5AuXZVIOfATk5VwE60bsSi0cSXgHCc7AjrKczkFCsCnFAEA2UeILhLMeK0VWKTpCcCb7kZnAUKgaqprKfantOVbTtO3VKH1IzoMKdQAAZNVdIDhG29iLaeyQogA1r4QLyfIKgQOwlgGSABEHCAAXwEdhLAIwiDLC9FVsOojCnGo5CKcGykQ1WFDAuQAAM2OEsKdD1fAhMVd4viCATRMEskNAULjzC0xV71gF9P1Bn9NAA2yU1ESDEBgxDUMEvDyzJASOJIGqjDJIwhFUOQO1JiAqjiJDbYS7UuKy8jCtK%20g5CIHLBHgwSYuapCFioDQiA4B2Ut66bBuKyjxv6-Lwqa1ruFwPDpB2w7tSrNLXuGx7KuMGrGtazZ0iaA9T03ZIfA4AQJCSz4ybADQYAMurDoM8ANipwAJDiSfCtONmAggkBGuoRgAERmC3T1VjZMOILuTet-YyQdxVgDoIF%20oVfjxomgTBz7XtBywVYAuCBfqBt7Xl%20kGxYAIiDcbxgBiILeCH-Lxz7QcFGGAIwgnHhZBLF-v%20cFbzeD4vq%20wGPjekGz7xv4VRxBVz7FVQuheA-4vzwBbqIFuvx-5gN-IAoqyEQEYXAZAzgLc2wJx7p3Qk3dYZ933APC4HdK6rhAKnWiY8J5TzArPeez5F60RXmvDez9d7-gPkfE%20Z9YJfivjfX8d9vwPyfrFRib8P5fx-n-WiACIJAOQaVMBECoEwLgf%20BBCikElVAWgluGCKo3Sttg2GT0E71xTlIIAA)